# Azure DevOps pipelines Windows VM Agents with Docker

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

Do Azure DevOps Release Pipelines support Agent Pools using Windows OS based images, which do have Docker preinstalled?

Or is it possible to install Docker on Windows VM agents? According to official docs, installing Docker requires VM reboot, so I assume rebooting the VM would cause whole workflow to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the agent software on your own Windows OS machine and use that as an agent as opposed to the devops pool. It will have access to resources such as docker that are available on the host machine.